# Remove all occurrences of char "." from string in Java

Tags: java, string

I would like to remove the period/decimal character from a `String` using `Java`.

```
 String originalString = "1.2345";
 originalString = originalString.replaceAll(".", "");
```

Printing `originalString` returns empty.

How can I remove `.` from `originalString`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of `replaceAll` is a regex pattern. Since `.` means "any character", all the characters are removed. In order to refer to the actual `.` character, you need to escape it:

```
originalString = originalString.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Comment: or just `originalString = originalString.replace(".", "");`

Answer (score 0):

```
String originalString = "1.2345";
originalString = originalString.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```